# Making an accordion expand on click and go to another page while remaining expanded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is the link to the codepen.
https://codepen.io/Cerebros/pen/VwMzdgR

What i am trying to achieve :
Currently when someone clicks on any part of the accordion tab it opens up the dropdown menu which is how it should be .
I would like it so that if someone clicks on the actual name of the accordion tab it would go to that respective page and also open the accordion on that page appropriately.

For example the first tab is Badminton. It has a dropdown of Event Images.
If i click Badminton it will go to the badminton page and also expand the dropdown below it to show the Event Image link.
If i click on Event image it would go to the event images page and keep the Badminton Tab expanded.

The accordion uses checkboxes to open and collapse it so what i tried was adding the following code :

```
    $("#idoflink").click(function(e) {
        if((e.target).tagName == 'INPUT') return true; 
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#idofcheckbox").prop("checked", !$("#idofcheckbox").prop("checked"));
      });
      </script>
```

What it would do is check if the link is clicked, then for that checkbox it would set the it to checked.
however the prevent Default sets it so that the link cant be clicked.

Any guidance on this would be appreciated.

Thank you,